# How to prints out the information about a list if info is in list and an error message otherwise

Tags: python

So I got this code that should let you display the information of a list if the 'name' is contained in the list. The list is loaded from `idel` by a different function `d = load_info('info.csv')`.

```
def display_info(name, info_list):
        for name[0] in info_list:
            if name[0] == name:
                print ' '.join(name)
                break
            else:
                print False
```

This function is run by this command `display_info('Greyson', d)`

However, I am getting this error

> TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment.

How do I fix this?

Comment: `for name[0] in info_list:` - what did you mean by that?

Comment: You can't do a for loop beginning with an index in a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def display_info(name, info_list):
        for i in info_list:
            if i == name:
                print ' '.join(name)
                break
            else:
                print False
```

`name` is a string here and string is immutable. So you can't use `name[0]` to iterate info_list, since only mutable item can be used to iterate a list.
Change `name[0]` to `i`(a mutable item)

Comment: ah i c, that great it works however, my output needs to have the comers and : looks something like this, Dick greyson: robin, nightwing, batman. something like that. i added ': '.join(each_info) but that seem to only add : to end of each string haha ...

Answer (score 0):

```
def display_info(name, info_list):
    for each_info in info_list:
        if each_info[0] == name:
            print ' '.join(each_info)
            break
        else:
            print False
```